# JsPdf add support for HTML colspan

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, jspdf

I am using `JsPDF` for to export a PDF.
It does not support HTML table colspan or CSS. So how can I export a complete pdf with a working HTML table with the CSS.

I have already tried with following `jsPlugins`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myproject/js/highcharts/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myproject/js/highcharts/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myproject/js/highcharts/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>headding 1</td>
        <td>headding 2</td>
        <td>headding 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td colspan="2" >col 2 and 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML($('#mytable').get(0), xx, yy+=60, {
    'width': 540,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

PDF output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In jsPDF directly adding CSS to pdf is not supported. But you can add limited styles using methods. If you are using php you can try mpdf. It supports adding css directly for java back end try iText and in .net you can try iTextSharp

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html

http://www.itextpdf.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but mpdf  is not lightweight.

Comment: Then I don't think you don't have any other option but to use the in built methods for styling